# Video.js scrolling overlay text

Tags: javascript, video.js

Is there any way to assign a simple overlay (infinite right to left scrolling) to videojs screen, which is also works in fullscreen on any device?

Comment: If I understood you correct, [this](https://github.com/xbgmsharp/videojs-watermark) is the plugin you need to make that work.

Comment: i found this: https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-overlay that's cool, but not working with a jquery marquee plugin...

Answer (score 1):

I develop a simple scrolling text overlay

https://github.com/Lethea/videojs-marquee-overlay-scrolling-text

You can check here.